# Developing a Turn-Based Battle Game

Tags: python

I am trying to create a turn based rpg game in python. Currently i am using the list method to display and create individual values for each role. For example,  the game allows player to setup a team of units for battle (minimum of 1 unit, default is 3). Each unit has a unique name and attributes like health point (HP), attack point (ATK), defence point (DEF), experience point (EXP) and a rank (default is level 1).
A unit can be either a Warrior, a Tanker or a Wizard whom have different strength in ATK and DEF point. In addition, a Wizard has special ability to cast spells that can impact friendly and enemy units (Heal, Poison, Cure, Freeze).

The suggested initial values for each unit’s attribute point are described in requirement details under Part A – Game Setup section.
The game will automatically setup either (1) player vs Artificial Intelligence (AI) or (2) two-player mode, of which both teams are made up of same number of units.
For AI team, the type of units will be assigned randomly or by specific AI algorithm. The name of units will be specified by the player, whereas AI unit names can be defined with prefix + random numbers (eg AI87).  For two-player mode, each player will be able to go through the same unit selection process either through console or GUI.
For each turn, player can select an active friendly unit (non-frozen or dead) to perform an action on a target unit. Units which are severely damaged (i.e. HP equals to or less than 0) will be considered killed (or flagged as “dead”).

How do I use Object Oriented Programming method to create the 3 characters with input name for each team (can display the name keyed and the information of each character), instead of use list method.

```
#Menu page
print('Welcome to PSB Battle Game! \n(N)ew game\n(S)ave game\n(Q)uit')

def main():
    selection = input('Choose your option then hit <ENTER> ==> ')
    if selection.upper() == 'N':
        new_game()              
    elif selection.upper() == 'S':
        print('Loading save game...')
        pass
    elif selection.upper() == 'Q':
        print('Exit game...')
        pass
    else:
        print("I don't understand what are you typing.")
        return main()

def new_game():
    print('\nSetting up Player 1 team...\n')
    name_list = []
    for unit_name in range(1,4):
        print(f'Enter a unique name for unit #{unit_name}-> ', end='')
        name = input('')
        repeated = False
        while repeated:
            if name == "":
                continue
        repeated = True
        if name in name_list:
            print('\nUnit name must be unique.\n')
            return new_game()
        if not name.strip():
            print('\nUnit name could not be blank.\n')
            return new_game()
        else:
            print('Name looks good!')
            name_list.append(name)
            print(f'Select unit #{unit_name}, type: (W)arrior, (T)anker, or Wi(Z)ard ==> ', end='')
            role = input('')
            if role.upper() == 'W':
                print('Added ' + str(name_list))
                warrior()
            elif role.upper() == 'T':
                print('Added ' + str(name_list))
                tanker()
            elif role.upper() == 'Z':
                print('Added ' + str(name_list))
                wizard()
            else:
                print("I don't understand what are you typing.")
                return role()


            
def warrior ():
    charac = [1,50,8,3,0,'True','False','False']
    print ('\nWarrior Level 1: ','HP =',charac[1],',''ATK =',charac[2],',''DEF =',charac[3],',''EXP =',charac[4],',''ALIVE =',charac[5],',''POISONED =',charac[6],',''FROZEN =',charac[7])
    print ()    

def tanker ():
    charac = [1,60,5,5,0,'True','False','False']
    print ('\nTanker Level 1: ','HP =',charac[1],',''ATK =',charac[2],',''DEF =',charac[3],',''EXP =',charac[4],',''ALIVE =',charac[5],',''POISONED =',charac[6],',''FROZEN =',charac[7])
    print ()           

def wizard ():
    charac = [1,40,3,2,0,'True','False','False']
    print ('\nWizard Level 1: ','HP =',charac[1],',''ATK =',charac[2],',''DEF =',charac[3],',''EXP =',charac[4],',''ALIVE =',charac[5],',''POISONED =',charac[6],',''FROZEN =',charac[7])
    print ()     

main()
```

Comment: Your characters are not actually created. You only print them and then all trace of their attributes is forgotten. The only thing you maintain is their names.

Comment: I am not sure how to do it, do you can guide me?

Comment: Your code is really miles away from what the task describes. As it stands, your question is too broad. You should remove the description of features that is unrelated to your question, and focus your question to just one problem you have, and only that. Leave all the rest out of the question. The thing is: it is unlikely that someone will solve the whole challenge for you. But we are willing to help out with one specific problem. But address one problem only.

Comment: This would be a really good opportunity to dig into OOP with a class of character that may have different values for type and stats. This class can then have methods to attack, defend, and move in the environment. You could also do them as large dictionaries, but OOP will save you time and worries, downstream.

Answer (score 1):

Your game is far from functional. I took the liberty of setting up a small sketch of a game after your design with battle functionality and character classes. From this code you can work forward to include other functionalities, such as chance, moving, changing skill points, and other stuff.

```
class Char:
    def __init__(self, name = '', cclass = "Warrior", stats = [1,50,5,5,0,'True','False','False']):
        self.c = cclass
        self.name = name
        self.stats = {'LVL':stats[0],
                      'HP':stats[1],
                      'ATK':stats[2],
                      'DEF':stats[3],
                      'EXP':stats[4],
                      'ALIVE':stats[5],
                      'POISONED':stats[6],
                      'FROZEN':stats[7]}
        self.calc_level()

    def __repr__(self):
        outs = ''
        outs+="Character Name: {0} of class {1}:\n---------------".format(self.name,self.c)
        for k,v in self.stats.items():
            outs+='\n  {0}: {1}'.format(k,v)
        return outs
        
    def calc_level(self):
        self.stats['LVL'] = int(self.stats['EXP']**.5)+1

    def attack(self,other):
        print("\n{0} furiously attacks {1} with {2} attack. {1} has {3} defense.".format(self.name,other.name,self.stats['ATK'],other.stats['DEF']))
        if self.stats['ATK']>=other.stats['DEF']:
            other.stats['HP'] -= self.stats['ATK']
            print("\nThat was a hit! The HP of {0} is now {1}".format(other.name,other.stats['HP']))
        else:
            print("\nYou missed and only made him angrier!")        

        
    
def new_char(existing):
    cc = ''
    accept = False
    while not accept:
        n = input("\nPlease input a new name: ")
        accept = True
        for c in existing:
            if n == c.name:
                accept = False
                print("This name is taken, already")
    while not cc in ['w','t','z']:
        cc = input("\nPlease input a class, noble {0}. (W)arrior, (T)ank, Wi(z)ard: ".format(n)).lower()

    cclasses = {'w':'Warrior','t':'Tank','z':'Wizard'}

    newc = Char(n,cclasses[cc])
    print('\nCharacter successfully created:')
    print(newc)
    return newc

def play(chars):
    print("May the games begin. The following characters are present:\n")
    for c in chars:
        print(c)
        print('')

    game_over = False   
    turn = 0
    while not game_over:
        print("It's the turn of noble {0} {1}. Please select a player to attack:".format(chars[turn].c,chars[turn].name))
        possible = []
        for i in range(len(chars)):
            if not i==turn:
                possible.append(i)
                print(" - ({0}): {1} named {2}".format(i,chars[i].c,chars[i].name))
        sel = -1
        while not sel in possible:
            s = input('Selection: ')
            try:
                sel = int(s)
            except:
                print("That's not a valid choice")

        chars[turn].attack(chars[sel])
        if chars[sel].stats['HP']<=0:
            game_over=True
            print("That was it! {0} has died and the game is over.".format(chars[sel].name))
        turn +=1
        if turn==len(chars):turn=0


def main():
    chars = []
    entry = ''
    print("Welcome to PSB Battle Game!")
    while not entry.lower() in ['q','p']:
        entry = input('\n(N)ew character\n(P)lay game\n(Q)uit\nSelection: ').lower()
        if entry == 'p' and len(chars)<2:
            print("\nYou can't play with only one character. Create characters first")
            entry = '' ## You can't play with only one char
        elif entry == 'n':
            chars.append(new_char(chars))
            entry = ''
        elif entry == 'p':
            play(chars)
        elif entry == 'q':
            print("\nOK, good bye")


main()
```

Comment: I am really appreciate your help, that's at least let me can move on, i have been stuck a week just because i am unable to create role, i will see study your code and million thanks !!

Comment: may I know how and where to add another stats for tanker and wizard as they are different with warrior?

Comment: In the `__init__()` method of the class, you can use an if-block to change the stats. (for example: `if self.c=="Wizard": self.stats["ATK"]=20`). But you could also give some random values to make it more interesting. Or let the user choose which skill to boost.